# IBM connections: marking todos complete has no effect on the last modification date of the activity?

Tags: ibm-connections

When I mark an activity in connections as complete, this update is not displayed on my activities overview page.

E.g. I have just marked one todo inside an activity as complete. However, when I go back to "Activities" tab to get an overview of all my activities, the displayed date says the last modification was yesterday.

How can I get to have the action "marking todos complete" to have an impact on the date of last modification?

Comment: You could always update the activity node, and say add a tag. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Updating_activity_nodes_ic50&content=apicontent

Comment: Hi @PaulBastide I don't want to make any other changes except marking a todo complete in order for the last modification date to be correctly displayed. Why can't IBM connections display the date of the true last modification? Inside the activity, you can see all recent updates including marking a todo as complete. Why does this update not affect the date displayed on the "My activities" overview? What do I need to do to suggest IBM to make this change inside the software directly?